# get all unique prefetch_related objects in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, prefetch

in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
...
class Product(models.Model):
   ...
   recommended = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
   ...
```

if i have a queryset of Product how can i get all unique recommended objects?
example: product «A» has 3 recommended products: «B», «C» and «D», product «B» has 2 recommended products: «C» and «E», in queryset «products» we have «A» and «B» products, in this example:

```
# get_products() returns QuerySet of «A» and «B» products
products = get_products().prefetch_related('recommended')
recommended = [item for p in products for item in p.recommended.all()]
```

we will get list of [«B», «C», «D», «C», «E»], but how to get only [«B», «C», «D», «E»]?

P.S. of course we can filter objects in «for» cycle, but maybe there's more effective and fair way?
...

#### Update #1 (answer to Mark Galloway):

```
products = self.request.basket.get_products().prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('recommended', queryset=models.Product.objects.distinct()))
recommended_list = [item for p in products for item in p.recommended.all()]
```

returns:

```
[<Product: Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in>, <Product: Vivamus quis turpis>, <Product: Pellentesque habitant>, <Product: Vivamus quis turpis>]
```

where `<Product: Vivamus quis turpis>` repeated

P.S. does anybody knows?

Answer (score 6):

You can define a more specific query for prefetch_releated by using a [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) object.

```
prefetch = Prefetch('recommended', queryset=Product.objects.distinct()))
products = get_products().prefetch_related(prefetch)
recommended_list = list(set([item for p in products for item in p.recommended.all()]))
```

Comment: @AntonVahmin I think the point is that this person is recommending converting the results to a set to eliminate duplicates, which doesn't actually fix your problem with the query returning duplicates, but does give you the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model is as follows (from your description and output, I am assuming you must have `symmetrical=False`):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    recommended = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name='recommended_by')
```

Then I think the following does what you are after:

```
Product.objects.filter(recommended_by__in=get_products()).distinct()
>>> <QuerySet [<Product: B>, <Product: C>, <Product: D>, <Product: E>]>
```